# Limit the number of rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I limit the number of rows in `Datagridview` column to lets say 50 record and place the other 50 into the next column on the same `Datagridview`? In my vb.net project I can't be scrolling up and down.

The Datagridview pull the data from an excel sheet.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Please, show some code how you add rows to datagridview? Or used `datagridview.DataSource`?

Comment: have u try my answer ? .. I saw your profile and you never vote someone's answer .. why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dataGridView1.RowCount = 50; //Let say we have 50 rows
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count >= 50)
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer but is the //TODO: that I don't know how.

Comment: its just was a hint or a comment, where your task will begin. hope it will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed this as single column table ..

```
dim tbl as DataTable       '--------> this is your displayed table
dim nLimit as Integer = 15 '----- this is your limit as you want
dim dc as DataColumn

'get column name
dim sCol as String = tbl.Columns(0).Name
dim nRow as Integer = tbl.rows.count

'how much column ?
dim n as Integer = nRow / nLimit 
if n * nLimit < nRow then n+= 1

for x as Integer = 1 to n
    dc = New DataColumn
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
    dc.Caption = sCol & n.ToString
    dc.ColumnName = sCol & n.ToString
    tbl.Columns.Add(dc)
next
```

Then you can show it ...